# show mobile website inside a desktop website

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, browser, user-agent

Hi I would like show a mobile version website in my website on a desktop computer, how I can do it?

- I was thinking using an iframe, but they show me the desktop version inside the iframe.
- I tried to change the user-agent of the iframe but doesn't work for me (maybe is possible)
- I don't want use chrome inspector to achieve this.
- I don't want use version like m.website.com because I don't know how to generate all the different URL
- I prefer a client solution without server if is possible
- If there is a solution out of the box I'll love have some working code

(for instance you can try https://www.linguee.it/)
Thanks

here you can see the problem 
`<iframe src="https://codepen.io" id="frame_1"></iframe>` https://codepen.io/orlandoangular/pen/qQXPob

Comment: Chrome developer tools - F12 and then you can click the small mobile like icon on top left

Comment: Chrome developer tools is not a website

Answer (score 0):

Add view port in header section like this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Use Media Query in your css like this:

```
body {
    background-color: pink;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    body {
        background-color: lightgreen;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry but your answer doesn't work, you can try here https://codepen.io/orlandoangular/pen/qQXPob

Comment: It's not a problem with the window size, but of the content of the webpage loaded